# How to split a number

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time, partitions

I have a number representing date (yyyymmdd):

```
19001231
```

I want to convert this number to

```
 {1900,12,31}
```

How to do this? There should be easy answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can also use `NumberDecompose` with the basis `{10000, 100, 1}`:

```
NumberDecompose[19001231, 10^{4, 2, 0}]
```

> ```
> {1900, 12, 31}
> ```

Comment: (+1). I did not even know about `NumberDecompose`

Comment: This looks the most elegant way!

Answer (score 12):

```
DateList[{IntegerString @ #, {"Year", "", "Month", "", "Day"}}][[;; 3]] & @ 19001231
```

> ```
> {1900, 12, 31}
> ```

```
DateObject[{IntegerString@#, {"Year", "", "Month", "", "Day"}}] & @ 19001231
```

> [image]

Answer (score 9):

Since the year is fixed 4 digits, and day and month are fixed 2 digits, one way is to do

```
n=19001231;
m=IntegerDigits[n];
FromDigits[#]&/@{m[[1;;4]],m[[5;;6]],m[[7;;8]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There might be a build in function that does this already related to date/time formatting. I have not looked.

Comment: +1 Note that the last line can be written more succinctly as `FromDigits /@ {m[[;; 4]], m[[5 ;; 6]], m[[7 ;;]]}`

Answer (score 9):

Yet another one-liner: [`FoldPairList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) + [`QuotientRemainder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuotientRemainder.html):

```
FoldPairList[QuotientRemainder, 19001231, 10^{4, 2, 0}]
```

> ```
> {1900, 12, 31}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

[`IntegerDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html) + [`MixedRadix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedRadix.html):

```
IntegerDigits[19001231, MixedRadix[{100, 100}]]
```

> ```
> {1900, 12, 31}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Interpret the string as a "Date".

```
Interpreter["Date"]["19001231"][#] & /@ {"Year", "Month", "Day"}
```

> `{1900, 12, 31}`

**EDIT**

I should have said: convert the number to string; interpret the string as a date and then extract parts (to answer the question as posed and also to avoid repeating the caculations).

```
str = IntegerString@19001112
dobj = Interpreter["Date"][str]
{y, m, d} = dobj[#] & /@ {"Year", "Month", "Day"}
```

`Interpreter` is slow, but it is a built-in function designed for the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know such a nice built-in function.

Comment: `f[#]&/@ ...` could be written as `f/@...`

Answer (score 6):

Processing dates by integers is extremely error-prone. Here is an example from the excellent book by Paul Wellin (p.598).

Compare this

```
DateList[19001231];
Take[%,3]

(* Out: {1900, 8, 8} *)
```

with this

```
DateList[ToString[19001231]] 
Take[%, 3]

(* Out: {1900, 12, 31} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to the response by @Nasser

```
MapAt[FromDigits, 
 TakeList[IntegerDigits[19001231], {4, 2, 2}], {{1}, {2}, {3}}]
```

which yields

> `{1900, 12, 31}`

Comment: (+1) Alternatively `FromDigits/@TakeList[IntegerDigits[19001231],{4,2,2}]` (which I was going to post!)

Comment: Also very nice, indeed!

Comment: @user1066 Beautiful!

Answer (score 4):

An option using the Date functionality:

```
  DateValue[#, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}] &@DateObject@ToString@19001231
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ToExpression @* StringJoin /@
 TakeList[Characters @ ToString[19001231], {4, 2, 2}]
```

> {1900, 12, 31}

Answer (score 4):

Using `DateString` and `StringSplit`:

```
dstr = DateString[ToString@19001231, "ISODate"]
```

> "1900-12-31"

```
ToExpression@StringSplit[dstr, Except[DigitCharacter]]
```

> {1900, 12, 31}

The shortest form (Thanks to @eldo!):

```
StringSplit[DateString[19001231, "ISODate"], "-"]
```

Comment: Very nice! Could be shortened to `StringSplit[DateString[19001231, "ISODate"], "-"]`

Comment: Thanks, @eldo! Let me add the shortest path you suggest ;)